# Using JS to create a "link" to a password protected site

Tags: javascript

Quite a few of the sites that the schools I work in use have user accounts to protect the content from people who haven't paid for it which means that the users (aged 5+) have to type in some pretty weird usernames/passwords before they can do their work.

I was wondering if it possible to use Javascript to create a page that would let me do something along the lines of:

1. Fetch the Login Page
2. Fill out the form
3. Submit It
4. Redirect the user to the site

1-3 would happen in the background without the user seeing it.

In most cases these accounts are *shared* and the details are on displays etc... in the classrooms so there is no issue with the details being publicly accessible.

I have used [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) in ruby before and would imagine a solution like it but running client side.

I know that some inspection of the target site will be needed but once I have an *in-principle* example I should be able to tailor it to each site later.

Comment: Wouldn't a standard password storing mechanism like most browsers have be easier?

Comment: Yes in principle but we are talking loads of users across loads of machines, maybe if I could deploy them through group policy but otherwise its not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a standardized browser, you should consider building a plugin for that browser, that's the easiest way to interact with the web pages. Otherwise you'll get into issues with anti-CSRF protections and cross-domain-policies.

As for the language, [Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) are written in javascript and are pretty easy to build.  For the other browsers I don't know.

Comment: Firefox is also built in a variant of javascript with some extra APIs and freedoms.

Comment: Might look into it, I liked the Idea of using JS on page so it could be integrated into the home page which already has links to these services.